# Multiple Inheritance with kwargs

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

## Problem

I came across this code in *Object Oriented Programming* by *Dusty Phillips* (simplified for brevity) and I unsure about a specific part of this definition.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c
```

---

## Questions

1. Since the method resolution order is `(__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, object)`, could `class B` be defined in the following way instead?

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
```

2. Isn't `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in `class B` redundant, since any surplus `kwargs` passed to `C` will be passed to `object`, raising?

> TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

3. Is this a safeguard for if `C` was defined as `class C(B, A)` instead of `class C(A, B)`?

Comment: You **cannot** know the `mro` of the derived classes. So `super` may not call `object.__init__` when the call comes from a certain subclass. This is why we don't use `object.__init__` directly... you want to ensure that you call the constructor of all the classes, the only way to do that is to use `super` and *always* call it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Because some *other* class might subclass `C`, and another call to `super().__init__` may have passed unexpected arguments to `C.__init__`. The right thing to do is to accept them, ignore them, and pass them on. `super` is used to support *cooperative* inheritance, and to do that right, you have to do things that aren't immediately necessary for *you*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is the how the example is demonstrated in the book. I just replaced the names here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the method resolution order is `(__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, object)`, could `class B` be defined in the following way instead?

No, because then this would fail:

```py
class D:
    def __init__(self, d, **kwargs):
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class E(C, D):
    def __init__(self, e, **kwargs):
        self.e = e
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

The MRO of `E` is `(E, C, A, B, D, object)`, so `B` must call `super().__init__` otherwise `D.__init__` won't be called.

> Isn't `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in `class B` redundant, since any surplus `kwargs` passed to `C` will be passed to `object`, raising?

No, because the surplus `kwargs` will go to `D.__init__` in the above example. But even without that, it is not redundant to raise an error when you call a constructor with too many arguments; it is desirable to have an error message informing you about your incorrect code, rather than for the mistake to go undetected.

> Is this a safeguard for if `C` was defined as `class C(B, A)` instead of `class C(A, B)`?

In some sense, sure; but really it's a safeguard for `B` occurring in *any* class hierarchy, so long as the other classes in the hierarchy follow the same rule of calling `super().__init__(**kwargs)`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider how you might instantiate `C`:

```
c = C(a=3, b=5, c=9)
```

`C.__init__` gets *all* the keyword arguments, but only uses the one for its own parameter `c`. The rest are passed on for the next `__init__` method in the chain. In this case, that's `A.__init__`, which "pulls out" the argument for `a` and passes `b` on to `B.__init__`. `B` uses that and passes on the (now-empty) set of keyword arguments to the *next* method, `object.__init__`. Because all keyword arguments have been "claimed" and processed by other classes, `object.__init__` succeeds.

Because of how the MRO is constructed, classes that properly use `super()` guarantee *collectively* that `**kwargs` will be empty by the time `object.__init__` is called.

Comment: Understood. So if `B` is defined as `class C(A,B)`, by the time `B` is called, `kwargs` should be empty? So `super()` isn't essential in the alternative definition, but advisable if the MRO is changed?

Comment: It's essential to ensure all applicable `__init__`s are called and called in the right order; consider some class `E` that inherits from `C` and a class `D` that inherits only from `A`. `E`'s MRO will probably look something like `[E, C, B, D, A, object]`. Without `super`, a call to `E()` cannot ensure that `D.__init__` gets called between `B.__init__` and `A.__init__`, considering that `B` doesn't "know" about `D`.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now

Answer (score 2):

In this example `B` would have worked the same if it was defined as you say (point 1) and `C` is as is (and there is no other use of it).

As for point 2: A call to constructor of `super()` would indeed fail as indicated, if there were still keyword arguments left, e.g.:

```
c = C(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
# -> TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

As the class `B` is (originally) written, it would be also OK if used in reverse order as you say, or if there was one (or) more super-class(es), e.g.:

```
class D:
    def __init__(self, d, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.d = d

class C(A,B,D):
    ...
```

Comment: In your example, if `B` is defined in the alternative way suggested, `C` would fail, unless `class C(A,D,B)` is called. As you pointed out, the way I defined `B` only works if it is called last. So perhaps the best way is to always call super as pointed out in the comments

Comment: If "alternative" `B` was used and was not last, it would just (silently "eat up" remaining `kwargs` and constructor of `D` would never be called (for `class C(A, B, D))`.