# How do I pass the same kwargs to all classes I inherit from?

Tags: python, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I am trying to write an `__init__` method for a class such that all the classes it derives from get the same set of keyword arguments. Let's say,

```py
class First(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(First, self).__init__()
        print('First', kwargs)

class Second(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Second, self).__init__()
        print('Second', kwargs)

class Third(First, Second):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Third, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Third', kwargs)
```

If I instantiate `Third` with a bunch of keywords, I can see that they all get "taken out" by the `__init__` method of `First`,

```ipython
In [5]: tc = Third(key='value', someother='nothing')
Second {}
First {'key': 'value', 'someother': 'nothing'}
Third {'key': 'value', 'someother': 'nothing'}
```

I understand that this is the expected behavior, so I'm not complaining. However, is there a way to write this class hierarchy such that **both** `First` and `Second` get the same set of `kwargs`? More generally, I'd like to write the hierarchy such that if `Third` derives from `N` classes, all `N` of those should get the same set of `kwargs` unless one of the explicitly pops one of the keys.

I have looked at other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75078418/422953), and answers have pointed out that that's not the default beahviour. I get that. But, **is there** a way to do it?

Comment: `super` is designed for *cooperative* inheritance. If you want to inherit from `First` and `Second`, either both must be designed to work when they aren't necessarily the last class in the MRO, or you need to inherit from adaptor classes based on `First` and `Second`.

Comment: Put another way, neither `First` nor `Second` can assume that `super().__init__()` is going to call `object.__init__`.

Comment: In fact, in cooperative classes, `__init__` should use the named args it knows and pass everything else to its parent.

Comment: Indeed: one should read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on *properly* designing classes intended for cooperative multiple inheritance (and specifically for defining `__init__` in such classes).

Comment: `object.__init__` doesn't even do anything anyway, so there's no point calling it except in the situation described in the linked blog post.

Comment: In short, accept arbitrary keyword arguments, *remove* the ones that you *know* aren't expected by any other class, and pass on the rest.